# django changing the db

Tags: python, django

i'm writing an app with django and i need to change a specific model when

ever it been saved. i.e lets say i have a model A and a client want to save

changes to that model - i need to also save a change (only if the client

changed a certain field) to the same model (not instance).

my code:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=A)
def my_callable(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    a = A.objects.filter(b=True).all()
    for my_a in a:
        my_a.b= False
        my_a.save()
```

i have 2 problems with that code:

1. it has an infinite recursion
2. i don't know how to check which field had changed

and ideas?

Comment: Where is the infinite recursion?

Comment: sorry, i edited the question (sender changed to A from Game)

Comment: Why `a.b = False` ? Is it `my_a.b = False` ?

Comment: You cannot create models "on the fly" in django.

Comment: edwin: yes it supposed to be "my_a.b = False". burhan - i don't create on the fly - im changing an existing instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.update(b=False)` on the queryset:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=A)
def my_callable(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    A.objects.filter(b=True).update(b=False)
```

The update is done in SQL, doesn't call model's `save()` method or trigger any signals

[.update() docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#update)

Comment: thx thats helped!! do you know how can i tell which field had changed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're able to use Django1.8, this exact use case is covered in the docs actually: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#customizing-model-loading

Cliff notes: use the from_db method to customize loading of the model and save a copy of the instance's attributes as it is loaded, and then compare them before it is saved.

If you want to compare form data to a model instance to see if a user is changing it, do that in the view, not with a signal.

Comment: the upgrade path between them is almost painless, and there are some cool new features, db functions like Lower and Coalesce are a boon. Also 1.8 is LTS, 1.7 support will be dropped in a few months once 1.9 comes out.